# Using one Google Checkout Button for multiple products

Tags: javascript, html, google-checkout

I'm wondering if anyone using Google Checkout has found a way to use one 'Add to Cart' button to add multiple items with different titles and prices.

In short, what I'm looking to do is, on a website with a non-customized Google Checkout system already in place, create a single page that allows customers to select products and required accessories for those products, get a quote, and click a single button to add all of their selections to the Google Cart.

Is there any way I can do this without completely replacing the existing cart system with an integrated self-built cart?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using the Checkout shopping cart JS API:

http://sites.google.com/site/checkoutshoppingcart/javascript-api

For example use one of the JavaScript hooks triggered by the Add to Cart button. On the callback, update the cart with the new items and quantities.